# Error installing bitarray. Wrong compiler?

Tags: python, linux, gcc, installation, bitarray

I need bitarray installed on my Ubuntu machine and the described ways won't work. Maybe someone has an idea what is going wrong. Looks like it's trying to run Python files as C code?

```
sudo pip install bitarray
```

> Downloading/unpacking bitarray   Downloading bitarray-0.8.1.tar.gz
>   (46kB): 46kB downloaded   Running setup.py
>   (path:/tmp/pip_build_root/bitarray/setup.py) egg_info for package
>   bitarray Installing collected packages: bitarray   Running setup.py
>   install for bitarray
>       building 'bitarray._bitarray' extension
>       gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.6 -c bitarray/_bitarray.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.6/bitarray/_bitarray.o
>       bitarray/_bitarray.c:9:20: error: Python.h: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
>       bitarray/_bitarray.c:71: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘PyObject_VAR_HEAD’
>       bitarray/_bitarray.c:82: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘Bitarraytype’

... and so on until:

> error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
>
> ---------------------------------------- Cleaning up... Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools,
>   tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip_build_root/bitarray/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open)(**file**).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), **file**,
>   'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-ABVXsZ-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/bitarray Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 11, in 
>       sys.exit(main())   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip/**init**.py", line 185, in
>   main
>       return command.main(cmd_args)   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161,
>   in main
>       text = '\n'.join(complete_log) UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 77: ordinal not in range(128)

Answer (score 0):

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 77: ordinal not in range(128)

Try setting the environment variable. Before installing , type the following in the shell :

PYTHONIOENCODING=utf_8

export PYTHONIOENCODING

Comment: unfortunately I get the same problem